# Maximum number of custom labels in AddressBook for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, addressbook

How many custom labels can we add in a contact in the AddressBook for iPhone programmatically?

I tried to add more than one label in but it is showing me only one custom label in a particualar contact. Is there any limitation provided in the iOS SDK that we can't add more then one label for a contact in the address book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no restriction, you'll only see one label for a particular value, so you'll need to make your own view (controller) to choose or change it - you see this in the Contacts app.